# Change selected day background (or text) in Calendar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm learning WPF and XAML. But i'm newbie and have a question.

My purpose - change text of selected day in calendar. Now, it has blue background. But i want two brackets: (...):

[image]

I see two solutions of this problem.

First. Change control template. I found [full template code on MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218.aspx). But there is too many code and i can't find any way to replace background color to brackets, cause i can't find "Text" property. If i find it, i just replace it by horizontal StackPanel and add two TextBox with "(" and ")" before and after date. But i can't. And if i can, i'm really should copy all this code?

Second. As i know, all days in calendar is CalendarDayButton type. This type has a "Context" property. Maybe, if i change it, then text is changed. I don't know. But i haven't direct access to this type. I should get all children items of calendar and search selected day among them. It's too complicated i think.

If you know more elegant solution of this problem - i will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so you answered your question with the first observation. So if we look at that code in the MSDN example given and focus on your `CalendarButton` `Style` Template you can break down how it works following along from top to bottom. See comments in copied example below.

```
         <!-- **********
            Ok, so we know this is the bugger we want to deal with.
            -->
            <Style TargetType="CalendarButton"
                   x:Key="CalendarButtonStyle">
              <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                      Value="40" />
              <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                      Value="42" />
              <Setter Property="FontSize"
                      Value="10" />
              <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                      Value="Center" />
              <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                      Value="Center" />
              <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarButton">
                    <Grid>
            <!-- *************
            What we want to change is the stuff that happens
        for a State, in this case the Selected State. So we just
        go look at what exactly it is doing for that Selected State.
            -->
                      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                          <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                          </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                          <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               To=".5"
                                               Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               To=".5"
                                               Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="SelectionStates">
                          <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                          </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualState Name="Unselected" />
            <!-- ************
        Hey, look at that. So this guy's telling something called "SelectedBackground" 
        with some opacity to show up and be seen. Now we know we need to go check out 
        this SelectedBackground object he's talking to.
            -->
                          <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               To=".75"
                                               Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="ActiveStates">
                          <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                          </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualState Name="Active" />
                          <VisualState Name="Inactive">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                              To="#FF777777" />
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                          <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                          </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualState Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="CalendarButtonFocusVisual"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <!-- ***************
            Sneaky bugger... looks like there is something called SelectedBackground
 (Rectangle) sitting here with a 0 opacity 
waiting to be told to show himself. 
    Imagine that.
            -->
                      <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground"
                                 RadiusX="1"
                                 RadiusY="1"
                                 Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                      </Rectangle>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="Background"
                                 RadiusX="1"
                                 RadiusY="1"
                                 Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                      </Rectangle>
                      <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        Margin="1,0,1,1">
                        <TextElement.Foreground>
                          <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF333333" />
                        </TextElement.Foreground>
                      </ContentPresenter>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusVisual"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                 RadiusX="1"
                                 RadiusY="1">
                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                      </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" />
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
```

So you've found the initial culprit. You could delete the `Rectangle` or just make it `Transparent` or something. Then go back to your `SelectedState` declaration in the `VisualStateManager` that was pointed out. 
Edit:
We'll take a different approach and show another element instead.;

```
<VisualState Name="Selected">
   <Storyboard>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedText"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Edit:

```
<!--
<ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  Margin="1,0,1,1">
                    <TextElement.Foreground>
                      <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF333333" />
                    </TextElement.Foreground>
                  </ContentPresenter>
-->
<TextBlock x:Name="NormalText"
           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
           Margin="1,0,1,1"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="SelectedText" Visibility="Collapsed"
           Text="{TemplateBinding Content, StringFormat='(\{\0})'}"
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
           Margin="1,0,1,1"/>
```

Now when the button is in the `SelectedState` it should display the `TextBlock` with the '( )` around it and hide the one that doesnt have it.

Anyhow this should give you a pretty decent direction, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It is really great answer. So, i understand how it work, but... Something is wrong. I have found "<VisualState Name="Selected">" in CalendarDayButtonStyle (not CalendarButtonStyle) and replace it to your code. But i have an runtime InvalidOperationException: "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'TextElement'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties." It is happen on line: "CustomCalendarControl.SelectedDate = CustomDateTime;". It's strange, cause CalendarDayButton is inheritor of Buton type and should have "TextElement" property.

Comment: No problem, see edit for the SelectedState and replacing the ContentPresenter. Hope this helps.

Comment: And new error: "Сannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance". I have found [7-year old issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/26/cannotanimateimmutableobjectinstance.aspx), but there are many reasons for this behaviour.

Comment: Right, immutable, sorry am not testing this as I go, literally just adjusting your template example freehand. Try the edit, this time a bit different approach.

Comment: Error: "The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'TemplateBindingExtension'". But i think, that i have found solution of this problem: [StringFormat in TemplateBinding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/3ac723c8-dcc3-491a-8bbc-8f2f21bfcad4/). I try to fix it. And write here about results.

Comment: I try [Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat={'(\{\0})'}}"] and [<TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}" Text="{Binding StringFormat='(\{\0})'}"/>] but in both cases i get "Сannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance" error again.

Comment: Then you can ignore using the VisualStates to do it all together and just attach a `DataTrigger` to the button itself to change the Text property on `IsSelected` instead. That I know will work but it would be attached to that button directly instead of in its Template.